# Set Tableview background with Image and Label

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xib

I have searched all over but haven't found the answer that works for me.
I just want a tableview background to be set with an Image and a Text below the image when there are no items in the tableview. Like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DZa5.png

It also has to be in the center and has to work in both iPhone and IPad.

I have tried setting the tableview background to an ImageView but I can't get the label to be positioned below the image. I have also tried creating a separate .xib file for this but I can't get it to work. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i have done it using ImageView and setting a label inside the imageview.. then adding the imageview as the background for the tableview. It works on iphone and ipad. here is the code:

```
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ico_file_list_not_found.png"];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
    imageView.image = image;
    [imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];

    UILabel *messageLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.tableView.bounds.size.width/2 - image.size.width / 2 + (image.size.width/7),
                                                                    self.tableView.bounds.size.height/2 + image.size.height / 2
                                                                    , 120, 21)];
    messageLbl.text = @"No files found.";
    [imageView addSubview:messageLbl];

    self.tableView.backgroundView = imageView;
```

thank  you

Answer (score 1):

Do you believe in magic ? Kidding...

I believe its not the background of table view. Whenever the array populating your table view contains no data, you need to remove the table view (_tableView.hidden = YES; WILL WORK) and add this custom view with your image and label.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you set the `UITableView`'s `background` property to clear. Then just set the image as the background of the `view` it self? Using `AutoLayout` will help you keep it centre at all times.

Answer (score 0):

It work for you

1> `IBOutlet lblTextlable` and `imgNoItem`

2> you set the UITableView's background property to clear.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    if (arrTableListItem.count==0) {
        lblTextlable.hidden = false;
        imgNoItem.hidden = false;
    }
    else {
        lblTextlable.hidden = true;
        imgNoItem.hidden = true;
    }
    return arrTableListItem.count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see in that image, it's the label and image. So the code logic maybe as follow:

1. If there is no item in list view, hide it and "show" the image / label.
2. If there are at least one item in the list view, show the list view and hide the Image / Label.